# PageWidth not inserting line breaks into long strings

Tags: output-formatting, files-and-directories

I am having some trouble setting the width of my output. I have some very long expressions, and I would like to output them as strings of maximum length 80 characters. For example, I have a very long expression "beta" and I would like to output to a file "RGEs_nicks.txt". So I have tried

```
streamM = OpenWrite["RGEs_nicks.txt", PageWidth -> 80];
WriteString[streamM, ToString[beta // InputForm]];
Close[streamM];
```

However, this is not putting in any line breaks, and the output is just one very long line. How do I get this to be formatted output? It works fine if I use just `Write` instead of `WriteString`, but I want to be able to add some other tricky stuff before and after so I need the `WriteString`. Any clues would be much appreciated!

Comment: Probably `#<>"\n"&/@StringPartition[ToString[beta // InputForm],UpTo[80]]` is what you need?

Comment: Thanks @Alx! However, this is not quite what I want, because I think this might break the string into pieces where things should not be split, for example in the middle of a variable. Might this happen?

Comment: Well, this might happen. Another idea: first determine positions of, e.g., spaces: `StringPosition[ToString[beta // InputForm], " "]`. Then choose from that positions those near to desired length of multiples of 80, and `StringInsert[ToString[beta // InputForm], "\n", {<positions>}]`.

Comment: What tricky stuff causes you to need to use WriteString?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you really need to use `WriteString` for some reason, you could use [`ExportString`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExportString.html), which respects `PageWidth`, to do the formatting for you:

```
streamM = OpenWrite["RGEs_nicks.txt"];
WriteString[streamM, ExportString[beta, "Package", PageWidth -> 80]];
Close[streamM];
```

The advantage of using `ExportString` is that it knows how to preserve a valid syntax when doing the line wrapping, as opposed to blind string splitting.